# How I can perform gravity to object until they touch floor in 2d in Java?

Tags: java, 2d, gravity

I study about physics in 2d in Java. At now I create balls and perform gravity to that. I increase y coordinate of all balls until ball touch to floor. The increase value is change like fall in real life. But it's not work correctly.

```
        if(e.getSource() == gravityTimer){
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++){

            if(circles.get(i).getY() + circles.get(i).getRadius() + fallingSpeds.get(i) <= 640){
                if(a%2==1)fallingSpeds.set(i,(fallingSpeds.get(i) + 1));// to increase one in two

                a++;
                if(!isHolding.get(i)){// I want don't move ball that holding
                    circles.get(i).setY(circles.get(i).getY() + fallingSpeds.get(i));
                }
            }else{fallingSpeds.set(i, 0);}
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I try that to understand that did a ball touched to floor. But sometimes balls can stay under floor or sink to floor.

Can you give me more correct approach?

Comment: Add more code. Fow now it's hard to say what this condition is used for

Comment: What is a? Explain fallingSpeds, please. And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Posting this as a comment as I'm guessing as you don't include the code that move the ball: You add a value on each step while the ball position is above the ground. On the last step before hitting the ground, condition is still true, so it add the mouvement that get it below the ground. You have to check if it will reaches below the ground before adding the mouvement and, if true, only add the delta value (position minus ground position) and not the full mouvement